# Unitialized unsigned signals

Tags: vhdl

Came across the following sample code:

```
architecture arch of disp_mux is
  constant N:integer :=18;
  signal q_reg, q_next: unsigned(N-1 downto 0);
  signal sel: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
  process(clk, reset)
  begin
    if reset='1' then
      q_reg <= (others=>'0');
    elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then
      q_reg <= q_next;
    end if;
  end process;
  q_next <= q_reg + 1;
  sel <= std_logic_vector(q_reg(N-1 downto N-2));
  process(sel, ...)
  begin
    case sel is...
    end case;
  end process;
end arch;
```

If you never write `1` to `reset`, what is the value of `q_reg`? And what happens at `q_next <= q_reg + 1;` when/if `q_reg` is `UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU` which is what I suspect it is.

Comment: `std_ulogic` is actually nothing more then an enumeration type, as described [here](https://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/std_logic_1164.vhdl). `'U'` is the first literal of the type and thus has position 0. An uninitialized object of an enumeration type will by default have the literal at position 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never write 1 to `reset`, `q_reg` is `"UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU"` and after executing `q_next <= q_reg + 1` `q_next` becomes `"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`.

Comment: My obvious follow-up is what will "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" + 1 become?

Comment: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" + 1 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Comment: @carlsb3rg look at the [`std_logic_1164` package body](https://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/std_logic_1164-body.vhdl). At the start you'll find the truth tables which lists all the combinations of `std_logic` values for basic logic operations (which form the basis of an adder)